# Yii2 advanced как подключить другие страницы и авторизоваться в админке?

Tags: mysql, yii2

В браузере на локальном сервере (Open Server) отображаются только первые страницы Home в fronted и backend в доменах site.com и admin.site.com но других страниц нет (about, contact, signup,login)везде ошибка? мне нужно зайти в админку как администратор, т.е. зарегистрироваться где-то. если правильно понимаю то это можно сделать в signup. База данных есть в MySQL с файлами migration и user.[image: скрин]

Comment: Ты их создавал?

Answer (score 0):

Решилось добавлением имени базы данных в файле yii2\common\config\main-local.php`mysql:host=localhost;dbname=locallhost',`